# utf-8 convertion doesn't work always

Tags: java, utf-8, screen-scraping

I searched into other stack before to type here and I didn't find anything similar.
I have to scrape different utf-8 webpages which contain text like

"Oggi è una bellissima giornata"

the problem is on the character "è"

I extract this text with jtidy and xpath query expression and I convert it with

```
byte[] content = filteredEncodedString.getBytes("utf-8");
String result = new String(content,"utf-8");
```

where filteredEncodedString contains the text "Oggi è una bellissima giornata".
This procedures works on the most webpages analyzed so far but in some case it doesn't extract a utf-8 string. Page encoding is always the same as the text is similar.

**Edit on September, 14th**

I modified my code as follow to get pages in utf-8 encoding:

```
URL url = new URL(currentUrl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), getEncode()));

        String line="";
        String domString="";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            domString+=line.toString();
        }

        byte[] bytes = domString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        in.close();

        return bytes;
        //return text.getBytes();
```

where **getEncode()** returns page encoding, utf-8 in this case. But I still noticed that ì or é are not read correctly.
there is something wrong with this code?
thanks again!

**Edited on October, 2nd**

This code seems to work. The problem was into a Dom Document creation I didn't posted (sorry about this!) with bytes returned from method above.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot "convert" a String to utf-8 after the fact.  if the bytes have been converted to chars incorrectly, then you have already lost the data.

Comment: unless you used a charset (like `ISO-8859-1`) that is a one-to-one mapping from bytes to chars. Most default charsets (`windows-12xx`) don't fall into that category though.

Comment: @mihi - yes, there are rare occasions where it might work, but in the general case, by the time you get the chars, you have already lost.

Comment: sure, but in case you don't have control over the library that converts to chars, you can often set system properties like `file.encoding` to "friendly" charsets as a workaround until the library gets fixed (if ever)

Comment: @mihi - heh, good point.  (as long as you don't have conflicting needs for the default encoding :) )

Comment: I updated the code according to yours suggestions. but I still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcoPiccinni - i would recommend reading the url content as _bytes_ and see if the characters are encoded as utf-8 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get your page as an array of bytes, not as a string and then to convert it with [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html) to a utf-8 string.

Comment: thanks, I did it but maybe there is something wrong with some page such as the most of them are parsed correctly even with special characters

Comment: Well, it's hard to say anything not seeng these pages and parse results. are you sure that **all** pages are in utf-8?

Comment: You're right but pages are all in utf-8 encoding and the result is the "è", for example, is replaced with A'', or something similar

Comment: I updated the code according to yours suggestions. but I still doesn't work. Any idea.

Comment: Well, I'm nearly out of ideas. You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934797/java-utf-8-encoding-not-set-to-urlconnection) question. Maybe you'll find something useful there.